# encodeURI() - результат с русскими символами

Tags: javascript, uri

Необходимо закодировать строку "тест!" в url с текстом "тест%21", на деле получается
"%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%21".

Использую encodeURI(), есть ли что-то подобное в JS, но допускающее русские символы?

Вот пример, где все прекрасно работает:

Пишем в поиске любую фразу, на выходе получаем примерно следующий url(не реклама):
[https://www.dns-shop.ru/search/?q=тест%21](https://www.dns-shop.ru/search/?q=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%21)

Comment: Ну вообще-то там всё очень даже закодировано как https://www.dns-shop.ru/search/?q=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%21 — просто браузер в адресной строке специально раскодирует, чтобы пользователю красиво было

Comment: А для чего вам такое надо сделать? Без знания этого не совсем понятно что делать.

Comment: То же, что и в примере, мне нужно сгенерировать русско-человеко-понятный url по результатам поиска по магазину, как в примере https://www.dns-shop.ru/search/?q=тест%21. Можно, конечно, кодировать руками, но должен быть вариант проще.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/987739/188366