# Как сделать, чтобы encodeURI не кодировал русские буквы?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы encodeURI не кодировал русские буквы?

Comment: Написать свой. Лучше расскажите зачем вы этого хотите

Answer (score 1):

Может так?

```js
let encode = s => s.split('').map(c => c.match(/[а-яА-Я]/) ? c : encodeURI(c)).join('')
console.log(encode("Привет hello %%%"))
```